# InvalidateRect then Cimage.Draw()

Tags: c++, mfc

I try to create small animation (a moving PNG object) using:

```
pDC -> GetWindow() -> InvalidateRect(lpRect); // Clear old Draw()
image.Draw(pDC -> GetSafeHdc(),MyBmpFile::Instance() -> getxDest(), MyBmpFile::Instance() -> getyDest(),50,50); // Draw my CImage
MyBmpFile::Instance() -> Update(pDC); // change xDest, yDest to new one, and move lpRect to new position
```

As long as I do not use `invalidate()` the PNG is drawing, but I need to clear the old one before I draw the next one. When the above code compiles, there is nothing in my dialog window.

Comment: You ought to write your answer as an answer to flag the question as been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the answer was simple : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yz8we9y(v=vs.80).aspx

I just need to `UpdateWindow()` after `invalidate();`